# C3680 with polish language strings

Tags: c++, visual-studio

installed new Visual Studio Version (Visual Studio 2015 Express instead of Visual Studio 2012).

A file with polish language strings doesn't compile anymore now, for example:

```
const char_t* const myString = "Wkr"oac"tce pojed"zac" w prawo.";   //ERROR C3680
```

What can I do?

Edit: Oh yeah, these triplets are macros like

```
#define oac "\xc3\xb3"
```

Regards

Comment: What exactly is `oac` / `zac`? Do you want to have double quotes in string?

Comment: More like you can't type in your language.

Comment: I'm not polish. I just have to debug the stuff.

Comment: `"Wkr"oac"tce pojed"zac" w prawo."` is not a valid C string so how can it compile before? Maybe you've opened it in the wrong charset. If you want to embed quote in a string, escape it with backslash like this `"\""`

Comment: What are the compiler errors ?

Comment: Compiler error is c3680

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding blank spaces before and after the macro names oac and zac:

```
const char_t* const myString = "Wkr" oac "tce pojed" zac " w prawo.";
```